# How to perform geospatial queries in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

I have using mongoose with NodeJS and have the following model:

```
var Post = new Schema({
  ...
  location: [Number, Number],
  ...
});
Post.index({ location: '2d' });
Post.set('autoIndex', false);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', Post);
```

When a user makes a query for all posts, they can add an optional query param *near* to find posts with locations within a given radius of *near*

```
GET /api/1.0/posts?near=12.3244,-1.23244
```

To get this to work, I'm doing the following:

```
if(req.query.near) {
  var loc = req.query.near.split(',');
  var area = { center: loc, radius: 10, unique: true, spherical: true };

  if(loc.length === 2) {
    query
      .where('location')
      .within()
      .circle(area);
  }
}
```

And then I execute the query.
I did this using [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-circle) mongoose documentation

I've got 3 questions:

1. What is the unit of radius, miles or kilometers?
2. Do I divide the radius by 3963.2 like it is done [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/) (the equatorial radius of the earth), or does mongoose handle that?
3. What does unique mean? (up above) and spherical? I'm supposing spherical means to use mongo's $centerSphere as opposed to $center, is that right?

I'd appreciate any help, especially for questions 2 and 1
Thanks :)

Comment: You are using legacy coordinate pairs so distances are in "radians" and conversions are described [here in the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/). Also if these are real world coordinates you need to make sure you are storing in "longitude" then "lattitude" order. For example google maps does this in reverse. GeoJSON format enforces the order for valid storage and all distances are in meters by standard. So you are likely better off changing to that.

Comment: Thanks, I've got the conversion sorted out. Now about the order of storage, it should be stored as `[longitude,latitude]` and when running queries, center will also be `[longitude,latitude]` **is this right?**

What if both became [latitude, longitude], would that affect the distance calculations?

Comment: Good. Are you also now understanding why your other questions are not relevant given that context? Spherical applies to "2dsphere" indexes, which you should be using for real world coordinates and which you also should be using GeoJSON if that is your intent. Another typical problem here is that people never define their schema correctly with mongoose for GeoJSON objects, and move away from it because their attempts at doing so failed. But it really is quite simple. Hint, "type" is a reserved word for mongoose schemas.

Comment: Yes, getting it now, also I've corrected the indexing to use `2dspheres` since all my data will be lat longs. I don't know what GeoJSON is (will look it up). I updated my earlier comment, I'm curious about what the consequence of inverting the coordinates would be, any idea?

Comment: The consequence is that your queries will actually work. MongoDB expects "longitude" and "latitude" in that order and regardless of the format. If you are doing any geospatial work then it is time you learned. MongoDB defintion for [GeoJSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/geojson/) and official spec for [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/). It's only a standard.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it right now.
Thanks again :)